# Continuously Redrawing a Path with Updated Data

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-2d, setneedsdisplay

I am developing an audio visualizer MacOS app, and I want to use Quartz/CoreGraphics to render the time-varying spectrum coordinated with the playing audio.  My Renderer code is:

```
import Cocoa
```

class Renderer: NSView {

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
    NSColor.white.setFill()
    bounds.fill()
    
    guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else {return}

    var x : CGFloat = 0.0
    var y : CGFloat = 0.0

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))

    for bin in 0 ..< 300 {
        x = CGFloat(bin)
        y = CGFloat(Global.spectrum[bin])
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
    }
    
    context.setStrokeColor(CGColor( red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
    context.setLineWidth(1.0)
    context.strokePath()

    self.setNeedsDisplay(dirtyRect)
}
```

}

This draws the path once - using the initial all-zeroes values of the spectrum[] array - and then continues to draw that same all-zeroes line indefinitely.  It does not update using the new values in the spectrum[] array.  I used a print() statement to verify that the values themselves are being updated, but the draw function does not redraw the path using the updated spectrum values.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you update the values, are you asking for the view to be refreshed, using something like setNeedsDisplay?  draw will only be called if the system thinks the window region needs to be redrawn.  It's not called at every refresh.

Comment: The last line in the above code is "setNeedsDisplay".  But it doesn't seem to do any good.  I suspect that I'm not using it correctly.  How do I call for a redraw on every refresh - or at least request it after every path draw?

Comment: Will you be drawing into a fixed width view or into a scroll view?  How is the data organized, ie are you getting a batch of points at intervals and if so where is the code for that?  Do you want to refresh the entire view at intervals or add data points to one side or the other, ie left to right or right to left?

Comment: There is no scrolling involved. I'm simply plotting the time-varying spectrum into a fixed-size NSRect.  spectrum[bin] is a 1D array of floats provided by AVAudioEngine and an FFT updated every 100 milliseconds. (Code to do that is lengthy and irrelevant to my rendering problem.)  I wish to redraw the entire path (not add points to it) from the spectrum array which is updated at 10 frames per second.

Comment: The place in my app that the spectrum array is updated is my AudioManager class which extends NSObject.  It does not know anything about an NSView, or NSRect, or a dirtyRect - which would be needed to insert "setNeedsDisplay".  So, I agree with you that the "setNeedsDisplay" call is key to solving my problem - but none of the ways I've tried to call it have worked.

Comment: It's usually not difficult to set up a global in Swift.  Just put 'var view : NSView!' at the top of your code, outside of a class structure and then 'view.needsDisplay = true' when you want to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following demo shows how to update an NSView with random numbers created by a timer in a separate class to hopefully mimic your project.  It may be run in Xcode by setting up a Swift project for MacOS, copy/pasting the source code into a new file called 'main.swift', and deleting the AppDelegate supplied by Apple.  A draw function similar to what you posted is used.

```
import Cocoa

var view : NSView!
var data = [Int]()

public extension Array where Element == Int {
    static func generateRandom(size: Int) -> [Int] {
        guard size > 0 else {
            return [Int]()
        }
        return Array(0..<size).shuffled()
    }
}

class DataManager: NSObject {
var timer:Timer!

@objc func fireTimer() {
data = Array.generateRandom(size:500)
view.needsDisplay = true
}

func startTimer(){
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopTimer() {
 timer?.invalidate()
}

}
let dataMgr = DataManager()

class View: NSView {

override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {
 super.draw(rect)
 NSColor.white.setFill()
 bounds.fill()
    
 guard let gc = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else {return}

  var xOld : CGFloat = 0.0
  var yOld : CGFloat = 0.0
  var xNew : CGFloat = 0.0
  var yNew : CGFloat = 0.0
  var counter : Int = 0

  gc.beginPath()
  gc.move(to: CGPoint(x: xOld, y: yOld))

  for i in 0 ..< data.count {
    xNew = CGFloat(counter)
    yNew = CGFloat(data[i])
    gc.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xNew, y: yNew))
    xOld = xNew;
    yOld = yNew;
    counter = counter + 1
  }
    
  gc.setStrokeColor(CGColor( red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
  gc.setLineWidth(1.0)
  gc.strokePath()
}

}

class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
 var window: NSWindow!

@objc func myStartAction(_ sender:AnyObject ) {
  dataMgr.startTimer()
}

@objc func myStopAction(_ sender:AnyObject ) {
  dataMgr.stopTimer()
}

func buildMenu() {
let mainMenu = NSMenu()
 NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
 // **** App menu **** //
 let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
 mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
 let appMenu = NSMenu()
 appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
 appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q") 
}

func buildWnd() {

data = Array.generateRandom(size: 500)

 let _wndW : CGFloat = 800
 let _wndH : CGFloat = 600

 window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH ), styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "Swift Test Window"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

// **** Start Button **** //
 let startBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( 30, 20, 95, 30 ))
 startBtn.bezelStyle = .rounded
 startBtn.title = "Start"
 startBtn.action = #selector(self.myStartAction(_:))
 window.contentView!.addSubview (startBtn)

// **** Stop Button **** //
 let stopBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( 230, 20, 95, 30 ))
 stopBtn.bezelStyle = .rounded
 stopBtn.title = "Stop"
 stopBtn.action = #selector(self.myStopAction(_:))
 window.contentView!.addSubview (stopBtn)

// **** Custom view **** //
 view = View( frame:NSMakeRect(20, 60, _wndW - 40, _wndH - 80)) 
 view.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]      
 window.contentView!.addSubview (view)
    
// **** Quit btn **** //
 let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 ))
 quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
 quitBtn.autoresizingMask = [.minXMargin,.maxYMargin]
 quitBtn.title = "Q"
 quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
 window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)
}
 
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildMenu()
 buildWnd()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}

}
let applicationDelegate = ApplicationDelegate()

// **** main.swift **** //
let application = NSApplication.shared
application.setActivationPolicy(NSApplication.ActivationPolicy.regular)
application.delegate = applicationDelegate
application.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
application.run()
```

Comment: apodidae, thank you very much for your recommended solution.  I have copied your code, and created the test project as your suggested.  It runs and shows a time-varying plot.  Now I need to study your code to see how I can adapt it into my project.  Preliminarily, I think that you have solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: apodidae, Thank you for solving my problem. Let me summarize your solution:  (1) Put "var view: NSView" at a top level in my project outside of a class structure.  This declares view as a global variable.  (2) Insert "'view.needsDisplay = true" right after the statement in my project that updates the data (in my case, after the AudioManager updates the spectrum[] array). (3)  Ensure that view actually points to the same NSView that my Renderer class is drawing into - using "view = Renderer( frame:NSMakeRect( ) )" and "window.contentView!.addSubview (view)" in setting up my project structure.